# Getting rid of input on JOptionPane frame?

Tags: java

I was wondering how to create a JOptionPane with a different title in the frame in the left corner other than "input" if that is even possible? I'm not really too sure. I would like for it to say what type of program I made.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a look at the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. Your question is really vague and shows no effort. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int messageType);
```

Input your title into the `String title` parameter to change it from input

Answer (score 0):

JOptionPane has a method

```
public static Object showInputDialog(Component parentComponent,
        Object message, String title, int messageType)
        throws HeadlessException;
```

just use it with `" "` title